# UINavigationController stacks UITabBarControllers which stack other UINavigationControllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I read that it is bad to have such structure in an iOS application. But what if an application has a lot of `UINavigationController`s and `UITabBarController`s. But one `UINavigationBar` and one `UITabBar` are always displayed only? Other `UINavigationBar`s and `UITabBar`s are hidden.

**EDITED**

For example, in navigation-based application I call this code:

```
- (IBAction)openTabsController:(id)sender {        

    tabOneController *tabOneViewContr = [[[tabOneController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabOneController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *tabOneNavContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabOneViewContr];

    tabTwoController *tabTwoViewContr = [[[tabTwoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabTwoController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *tabTwoNavContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabTwoViewContr];


    UITabBarController *tabContr = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    tabContr.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabOneNavContr,tabTwoNavContr, nil];
    sel.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabContr animated:YES];
}
```

After calling of this method I have two `UINavigationController`s and one `UITabBarController`. At the same time I have one `UINavigationBar` and one `UITabBar` on a screen.

**EDITED**

Approximate scheme.

[image]

From The beginning we have an UINavigationController which allows to navigate between the views (circles). Then after pushing an UITabBar appears and allows to switch between the views. A rectangle with two little rects is a view with a UITabBar with 2 UITabBarItem s. When we presss any UITabBarItem another UIView appears. In this UIView we can press some button which calls another view with another UITabBar. Current UITabBar is visible after pushing if it is not hidden with another UITabBar.
is it more clear now?
The code above works almost perfect (except of some animations and not including Apple's limitations)

Comment: You should post some code or the your app design to understand your question..

Comment: Is this code enough for understanding?

Comment: it is not my idea to make a such sctructure of application. So don't downvote please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gargo,

I'm not sure I understood your question but the apple documentation is clear. If you use `- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` it says that `viewController`:

> **cannot be an instance of tab bar controller** and it must not already be
>   on the navigation stack.

Since you do

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabContr animated:YES];
```

you are pushing a tab bar controller instance within the navigation stack.

If you add the structure that you would achieve maybe I can help you to find another solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you give me a link if it is possible?

Comment: @Gargo what type of link do I have to provide? Thanks.

Comment: a link where have you read about this? As I understand all the Apple's documentation is online.

Comment: Here the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html. Let me know if you want something else. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

An app should only have one working tabBarController at any one time.

A tabBarController should also be the root view controller. Always. (If you need a login view or similar before the tabBarController, then remove the login view, create the tabBarController and then make that the root).

This is Apple' advice spoken to me personally by Apple engineers.

Remember, apps should be small applications that are quick and easy to use/navigate. If you feel the need for more than one tabBarController then your app design is likely very wrong from a UI/Usability perspective.

Comment: As I have already said it is not my idea of such interface. The application look likes as if it has one working UITabBarController at any one time, but it is implemented as some UITabBarControllers

Comment: TabBarControllers should always be the root view controller according to Apple. Therefore you cannot have more than one "loaded". In your scenario none of the TabBarControllers are root. Just hiding it or having it earlier in a navigation stack doesn't cut it.